# SQL SUM based on prior SUM result

Tags: sql, sum

Been working with C# for a while and seem to have forgotten some basic SQL
After much Googling around, just can't seem to get anywhere.
How do I use the 'Result' of a sum as an input to another function?
Looking for option A rather than B

a) SELECT Col1,Col2, SUM(Col1*Col2) AS 'Result', SUM(Result/10) AS 'Final' FROM ... GROUP BY

b) SELECT Col1,Col2, SUM(Col1*Col2) AS 'Result', SUM(SUM(Col1*Col2)/10) AS 'Final' FROM ...

Answer (score 0):

You don't.  The correct calculation would seem to be:

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, SUM(Col1*Col2) AS Result,
       SUM(Col1 * Col2 / 10) AS Final
FROM ...
GROUP BY
```

SQL in general does not allow you to re-use aliases in an expression.  So, you need to repeat the expression, use a CTE, or use a subquery.

In addition, nested aggregation functions are not supported by Standard SQL.

Comment: Yeah, option B was the only way I could come up with without CTE. Thank you